# WCF IIS SQL problem

Tags: sql-server, wcf, iis

I have local IIS server, local SQL server and  WCF test service with 3 interface methods:

```
[OperationContract]
string GetData(int value);

[OperationContract]
CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite);

[OperationContract]
string getFirstName();
```

The first two is the VS template, and I've added the `getFirstName()` method

```
{
   //very basic 
   string connectionString = @"Data Source=.\SqlExpress;Initial Catalog=ProjectDB;Integrated Security=True";

   SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
   con.Open();

   SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select * from messages;", con);

   DataTable table = new DataTable();

   SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
   adapter.Fill(table);

   con.close();

   return table.Rows[0][3].ToString();
}
```

When I'm testing the invocation on VS's WCF Test Client, all the methods running as they should.

When the service is published to local IIS with VS wizard (publish -> Local IIS -> MyTestWeb Site) I get error when trying to invoke `getFirstName()` (the authentication method of SQL is windows authentication ).

Other methods  :

```
CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite);
```

and

```
string GetData(int value);
```

work perfect on both on VS development server and local IIS server.

Thanks .

Comment: **WHAT** error do you get?? Please tell us - we can't see and read your screen!

Comment: You mean you're not using the new .NET 4.5 System.ESP.dll assembly?  It's still in CTP but it has a go-live license.

Comment: marc_s I cannot actually see the error\exception ( because I don't know how to do so  on service running on IIS) , but I tried to provide stuff that do work.Be glad to know how to catch errors on IIS (still a newbie in that). thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, your error occurs because you're connecting to SQL Server Express using integrated security, and in IIS, this means the identity which is running IIS, and that account will most likely **not** be permissioned on your SQL Server instance.

Another recommendation: you should improve your ADO.NET code!

- use `using(.....) { .... }` blocks for protecting your disposable entities (**especially** important in a WCF environment!)
- don't create a `SqlDataAdapter` and a `DataTable` just to read a single column value......

My recommendation would be something like this:

```
public string GetFirstName()
{
   string firstName = string.Empty;

   string connectionString = @"Data Source=.\SqlExpress;Initial Catalog=ProjectDB;Integrated Security=True";

   using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
   using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT FirstName FROM dbo.Messages", con))
   {
       con.Open();

       using(SqlDataReader rdr = command.ExecuteReader())
       {
          if(rdr.Read())
          {
             firstName = rdr.GetString(0); // read column no. 0
          }

          rdr.Close();
       }

       con.close();
   }

   return firstName;
}
```

This is not solving your current problem, but it might help you avoid future (and hard to find/track) ones!

Comment: .. Thank you for the answer  , it was really an userAuthority issue.

Answer (score 1):

Further on retrieving a single value from back-end, most appropriate method to use would probably be "ExecuteScalar", which is specifically designed for the task as name suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at my answer to this question: [WCF service works in cassini, but not in IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5553076/wcf-service-works-in-cassini-but-not-in-iis/5553340#5553340)

It looks like you have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it's probably permissions. Make sure that the user your site runs as has permissions to your SQL Server database - for example, NT Authority\SYSTEM (this will depend on your version of IIS).